# Prove that difference of next and previous terms of the Fibonacci sequence and the square of the current term is $\pm 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

Given the Fibonacci sequence $f_{n+1}=f_{n}+f_{n+1}$, how would I prove that   \begin{equation}
    f_{n+1}*f_{n-1} - f_{n}^2 = 
    \begin{cases}
      1, & n \text{ odd}\\
      -1, & n \text{ even}
    \end{cases}
, \forall n
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really easy if we notice that

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}^n=
\begin{pmatrix}
F_{n+1} & F_n\\
F_n & F_{n-1}\\
\end{pmatrix}$

with $F_0=0,F_1=1,F_2=1\dots$

Now notice that the determinant of the left matrix is $-1^n$ and the determinant of the matrix on the right is $F_{n+1}F_{n-1}-F_n^2$